# TreeForm display with nested lists as nodes

Tags: visualization, trees

If i have a nested list representing nodes in a binary tree, `{3, {2, {1, None, None}, None}, None}`, what is the easiest way to show the hierarchy, without all the List heads being displayed as intermediate nodes?

Comment: Please give an example of what you *do* want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you want with your example input is the following

```
tree = {3, {2, {1, None, None}, None}, None};
TreeForm[tree //. {root_, left_, right_} :> root[left, right]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]